# Two methods to insert Matlab code into Latex

Tags: pdftex

I have two methods to insert Matlab code into Latex. But both of them have a disadvantage that I want to change. Firstly, I show my code and result:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{listings} %code extracts
\usepackage{xcolor} %custom colours
\usepackage{mdframed} %nice frames
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95} %the shade of grey that stack exchange uses


\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{Example using minted package}:
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=bg]{matlab}

A = [1 0; 2 4];
B = [5 9; 2 1];

if isequal(size(A),size(B))
    C = A + B;
end
C

>>

C =

     6     9
     4     5
     
\end{minted}

\noindent \textbf{Example using mdframed package}:
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=light-gray, roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, innerleftmargin=15, innertopmargin=15,innerbottommargin=15, outerlinewidth=1, linecolor=light-gray]
\begin{lstlisting}[language = matlab]
A = [1 0; 2 4];
B = [5 9; 2 1];

if isequal(size(A),size(B))
    C = A + B;
end
C

>>

C =

     6     9
     4     5
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

I would like to know how to change the font type from eg.1 to eg.2, because the font type in eg.2 is more beautiful. Or how to change the color of keywords in eg.2 from black to colorful?

I have no idea how to fix them. Please help me. Thanks in advance!